# sqlcmd xml output from SQL Server Agent Job truncates XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, powershell, sqlcmd

I have an SQL Server Agent job (which is going to be set to run on a schedule) to retrieve data on a daily basis.

The 2 steps involved in the automated job are as follows:

Step 1. 
Using T-SQL Execute the following query

> SET NOCOUNT ON;
>   declare @xml xml
>   set @xml = (select a AS a, b AS b from tableName for xml path ('path'), ROOT('paths'))
>   select @xml as returnXml

Step 2. Using the following command in Powershell remove the first 4 lines so that any headers are removed

> (Get-Content "C:\cmd\xml.xml" | Where {$_.ReadCount -gt 4}) | Set-Content "C:\cmd\xml.xml"

Now when I look at the output file I get this message:
String data, right truncation [SQLSTATE 01004]

And  I can see that at the end of the file it's just cut some of the xml off, it doesn't even finish with a proper end tag.

Any ideas on how I can get over this? Also for it to come out in proper XML format would be sweet, rather than just one longgg chunk

I've read about using :XML ON when using sqlcmd but I haven't had any luck with that :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test similar to your setup. I noticed that the XML gets truncated at 64,514 characters. This is really close to a magic number of 2^16 = 65,536. I'm guessing that you're hitting a data cap somewhere. You can try limiting you query to a `TOP 50000` or so and do it in batches.